# Forward to a Friend

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have just started trying my hands on FTAF. Have been able to get it working successfully. Got a couple of questions -

1. Can we customize the FTAF page and do some branding there? The default one is very basic one
2. By default the email address is assigned as the SubscriberKey. Can I change that behavior?

Regards
Maneesh

Answer (score 1):

1. The FTAF landing page is not customizable.  Custom versions would need to be built from the ground up.
2. No. The issue here is that you could forward to anybody - we have no guarantees they already exist in the All Subscribers, so no real method to develop a subscriber key.  Agree that the functionality to assign a derive a subscriber key would be a welcome one, but not one that currently exists.

Comment: In regards to this answer "The FTAF landing page is not customizable. Custom versions would need to be built from the ground up." Will it ever be customizable? What exactly do you mean when you say "would have to be built from the ground up?" Can we do this now?

Comment: I cant really comment on whether it will be customizable in the future.   

By building from the group up, I mean building one from scratch on a landing page using ampscipt, ssjs, or some other client side language.